# Radio Button Getting Value

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have some html like this

```
<form id="reportform" method='post'>
<input type='hidden' id='qid' name='qid' value="<?php echo $id ?>" />
<span><input type="radio" id="reporttp" name="reporttp" value="spam" /> spam</span>
<span><input type="radio" id="reporttp" name="reporttp" value="attack" /> attacking</span>
<span><input type="radio" id="reporttp" name="reporttp" value="nonsense" /> nonsense</span>
<span><input type="radio" id="reporttp" name="reporttp" value="other" /> other</span
<input type="image" name='Submit' value='Submit' src="../Images/buttons/reportButton.png"/>
</form>
```

when i try to read the value in    `$('#reportform').submit(function() {`

i read it as `$(reportttp).attr("value")`. And then i did some posting (which works fine). The problem is I always get "spam" postedf to me even though i select the other radio boxes. If i switch the first and second radio button around, ill get "attacking".... Could you tell me what is wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**You cannot have multiple elements with the same id**

I assume you want to read the checked radio button's value?  Is so, give them all unique ids, then do:

```
$("input[type='radio']:checked", "#reportform").val();
```

This will grab all radio buttons inside of you `reportform`, grab the checked one, then retrieve its value.

Answer (score 2):

My guess is that your names and ids for each radio button are identical, causing the browser to make weird decisions arbitrarily.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to Adam's answer, this is also invalid:

```
$(reportttp).attr("value")
```

should be

```
$('input[name="reportttp"]').val()
```

and I hereby retract my statement cause Adam updated his answer to a much better one.

and get rid of the duplicate id's

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do $('#reportttp').val() to get the selected value.